# How to drill down the performance Issue in New Relic Nodejs/Middleware/restify/*

Tags: performance, performance-testing, middleware, newrelic, restify

I am trying to understand the performance issue in one of the PUT API, which basically updates the existing playlist. In New Relic, all I can view is more than average 6 seconds are consumed by segment *Nodejs/Middleware/Restify/*Playlist//playlists/playlists/:id* in the breakdown in New Relic.
How I can drill more down here? How I can point out which part of the code, function etc. is causing this delay ?
Please refer the screenshot as below.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [Transaction Trace](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/transaction-traces/introduction-transaction-traces/). Traces are captured for the slowest transactions each minute. If this isn’t the slowest transaction, you can create a [key transaction](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/key-transactions/introduction-key-transactions) for this transaction and adjust the Apdex threshold for that new key transaction to increase the likelihood of the agent creating the trace.